# Filtering a nested array based on Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an nested array and want to remove the entries that matches the info on my model.

My array looks roughly like this:

```
[{"id"=>"72157627540544488", "primary"=>"6090588224", "photos"=>"49", "videos"=>0, "title"=>"Title1", "description"=>""},
{"id"=>"72157627309708150", "primary"=>"5987891163", "photos"=>"49", "videos"=>0, "title"=>"Title2", "description"=>""},
{"id"=>"72157626646787712", "primary"=>"5687687064", "photos"=>"11", "videos"=>0, "title"=>"Title3", "description"=>""},
{"id"=>"72157626646672290", "primary"=>"5687629990", "photos"=>"33", "videos"=>0, "title"=>"Title4", "description"=>""}]
```

And my model:

```
id               :integer         not null, primary key
name             :string(255)
set_id           :integer
thumb_url        :string(255)
created_at       :datetime
updated_at       :datetime
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to remove from the array all the elements where the value of `id` is duplicated in any of the `set_id` in my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
array.reject{|element| Model.exists?(:set_id => element['id'])}
```

where array is the array and Model is the model class. This will return a new array with the elements with duplicate id's removed.

[Array.reject](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-reject) returns a copy of the array without the elements where the block passed in returns true.

[ActiveRecord.exists?](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) returns true if a model exists in the database with the given conditions.

Comment: It worked! Just wondering if there's a way to do the same but using another array instead of a Model. Would `include?` do the trick?

Comment: I tried to do the same but using a instance variable instead of the Model to avoid another query to the database. I came up with this: 'array.reject{|element| @variable.any?{|item| item.set_id == element['id']}}'

Comment: Yep, that works. I can't really think of a more concise way to do that with an array.